# Is there any other way to test the Javascript Stimulus using rails Rspec

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, stimulusjs

I am using this code of stimulus in want to make test cases using Rspec

```
 update(){
    this.submitForm()
  }
  async submitForm(){
    const organizationId = this.organizationTarget.value;

    var endpoint = this.updateInvoiceTarget.value
    var invoiceId = this.updateInvoiceTarget.getAttribute("data-invoice-id")
    console.log("invoice_path "+ endpoint)
    try {
      const result = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "X-CSRF-Token": this.getMetaValue("csrf-token"),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "invoice_id": invoiceId, "organization_id": organizationId }),
      });
      const data = await result.json();
      console.log(data)
      if (data.code == 200) {
          console.log("SUCCES")
          var row = document.getElementById("invoices_list_"+invoiceId);
          if (row) {
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
          }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

I want to get the expected result data using Rspec rails.

Comment: Any other way than *what*? What is it you have actually attempted or researched to solve your issue?